# Brother Printer total print pages

Tags: printer

How can I check my printers (MFC-J625DDW) total print pages by computer or printer?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles across this question looking for the same answer, the page count should be listed on the *user settings report*.  Instructions for printing that report are on page 37 of the [Advanced User's Guide](http://download.brother.com/welcome/doc002869/cv_mfc625dw_use_ausr.pdf), but basically it's just:

**Menu > Print Reports > User Settings > Start**

If the page count isn't listed on the user settings report, then you'll have to get it from the web interface as @hdhondt suggested.

Answer (score -1):

The MFC-J625DW has a network interface (WiFi). If you type the printer's IP address into the URL box of your browser, you will see the printer's internal web page where you can find the page count.